# How to open an Excel workbook in Java and delete all sheets that ONLY have a header row

Tags: java, excel

I need to loop through all sheets in a workbook and delete the sheets that ONLY have a header. I have this currently:

```
public class DeleteExcelSheets {


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    //obtaining input bytes from a file
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\TwoNewProductsTestJava.xls"));
    //creating workbook instance that refers to .xls file
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
    //creating a Sheet object to retrieve the object
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    //evaluating cell type
    FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator=wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

    if (sheet.getLastRowNum() == 0){
        // delete the sheet
    }
}
}
```

So I have the logic to determine the sheet that I want to delete, but not seeing how to actually delete the entire sheet and not just the data within it. Apparently `sheet.removeSheetAt()` no longer works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do so like this:

```
public class DeleteExcelSheets {
static String xlsPath = "C:\\Users\\TwoNewProductsTestJava.xls";
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    DeleteEmptySheetsFromWB();

}

public static void DeleteEmptySheetsFromWB() throws IOException {
    //obtaining input bytes from a file
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(xlsPath));
    //creating workbook instance that refers to .xls file
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);


    for (int i = wb.getNumberOfSheets() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(i);
        if (sheet.getLastRowNum() == 0) {
            // delete the sheet
            removeSheetFromWB(sheet.getSheetName(), wb);
            System.out.println("deleting sheet");
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(xlsPath);
            wb.write(out);
            out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Caught Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public static void removeSheetFromWB(String sheetName, HSSFWorkbook book) {
    for (int i = book.getNumberOfSheets() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.println(i);
        HSSFSheet tmpSheet = book.getSheetAt(i);
        if (tmpSheet.getSheetName().equals(sheetName)) {
            book.removeSheetAt(i);
        }
    }
}}
```

So `removeSheetAt(i);` does work, I was just using it incorrectly before.